# client.watchQuery cannot be called with fetchPolicy set to "standby"

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have run into an issue with @apollo/client. I get this error on v3.4.17 and v3.4.0 which were mentioned in earlier posts. I think the issue is caused by @apollo/react-hooks.
This is my package.json

```
"@apollo/client": "~3.4.17",
   "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
   "@apollo/react-ssr": "^4.0.0",
```

but my package-lock.json looks like this

```
 "@apollo/react-hooks": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@apollo/react-hooks/-/react-hooks-4.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-fCu0cbne3gbUl0QbA8X4L33iuuFVQbC5Jo2MIKRK8CyawR6PoxDpFdFA1kc6033ODZuZZ9Eo4RdeJFlFIIYcLA==",
      "requires": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": {
          "version": "3.6.9",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@apollo/client/-/client-3.6.9.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Y1yu8qa2YeaCUBVuw08x8NHenFi0sw2I3KCu7Kw9mDSu86HmmtHJkCAifKVrN2iPgDTW/BbP3EpSV8/EQCcxZA==",
          "requires": {
            "@graphql-typed-document-node/core": "^3.1.1",
            "@wry/context": "^0.6.0",
            "@wry/equality": "^0.5.0",
            "@wry/trie": "^0.3.0",
            "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
            "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
            "optimism": "^0.16.1",
            "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
            "symbol-observable": "^4.0.0",
            "ts-invariant": "^0.10.3",
            "tslib": "^2.3.0",
            "zen-observable-ts": "^1.2.5"
          }
        },
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the version of `"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"` to `"@apollo/react-hooks": "~3.1.3"` in the package.json is working for me.

The `"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"` requires the internal dependency of `"@apollo/client": "^3.6.9"` which is causing the issue. **So downgrading the version of `@apollo/client` won't work when `"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"` is used.**